# Sonarqube starts on Ubuntu 16.04 but i can't reach it

Tags: sonarqube, ubuntu-16.04

I fixed all bugs of my sonar instance.
There are no errors in the logs.

[image: Screenshot of the service status]

But if i try to reach it wiht IP:9000 there is no website (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).

I also opened the port on the firewall (ufw & exoscale)

[image: ufw from my instance]

Do i need a webserver? I use sonarqube-7.3

Comment: Can you describe what you have configured in the SonarQube configuration file?

Comment: @JeroenHeier i fixed it with more memory :) But there was never an error :(